# in netsuite advanced pdf im looking to put an asterisk next to my date in my customer statement if the date has elapsed

Tags: html, netsuite, freemarker

In oracle NetSuite advanced pdf I've being trying to put an asterisk next to a date. With the current free marker I have, the calculation for daysoverdue gt 0 does not work. If I were to take out the has content condition in the if statement then it would only error out when I try to print the statement. with the current free marker the else statement is returning. I did test by changing line.datecol in the else statement to see if it would populate the daysoverdue which it did.

```
<#if line.duedate?is_date_like>
  <#assign d2 = line.duedate?long>
  <#assign daysoverdue = ((.now?date?long - d2) / (24*60*60*1000))?floor>
<#else>
  <#assign d2 = "">
  <#assign daysoverdue = "">
</#if>
    
<tr>
<#if line.datecol?has_content && daysoverdue gt 0>
  <td colspan="3">${line.datecol}* </td>
<#else>
  <td colspan="3">${line.datecol}</td>
</#if>
<td colspan="12">${line.description}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<#if statement.currency == "US Dollar"> <#if line.custbody_mes_invl_end_customer_link?has_content><a href="${line.custbody_mes_invl_end_customer_link}">Pay Invoice</a></#if></#if></td>
<td align="right" colspan="3">${line.charge}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${line.payment}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${line.balance}</td>
</tr>
</#list><!-- end items --></table>
```